# Getting logged in users with a SessionRegistry

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

I have a web application that is secured totally by the Weblogic container. Now I have to list the currently logged in users. I have to use Spring Security 2.0.4 for that

In web.xml I defined the necessary listener and filter:

```xml
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.ui.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Spring Security Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy</param-value>
        </init-param> 
    </filter>


    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Spring Security Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

After that I defined the beans as I understood this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans>

<bean id="filterChainProxy"
        class="org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy">
        <property name="filterInvocationDefinitionSource">
            <value>
                CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON
                PATTERN_TYPE_APACHE_ANT
                /**=httpSessionIntegrationFilter,logoutFilter,exceptionTranslationFilter,concurrencyFilter
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="httpSessionIntegrationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter" />

    <bean id="logoutFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter">
        <constructor-arg value="/logout.html" />
        <!-- URL redirected to after logout -->
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.ui.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_acegi_logout" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.concurrent.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
      <property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistryBean"/>
      <property name="expiredUrl" value="/session-expired.htm"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
        <property name="loginFormUrl">
            <value>/</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationEntryPoint"
            ref="authenticationEntryPoint" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionRegistryBean" class="org.springframework.security.concurrent.SessionRegistryImpl">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Finally I wrote a simple JSP page that lists the users:

```
  <body>
    <% 

    ApplicationContext appContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request.getSession().getServletContext());
    ActiveSessions as = new ActiveSessions(appContext);
    for(String u : as.getUsers()) {
      %>
        <ul><li><% out.println(u); %></li></ul>
        <% 
    }
    %>
  </body>
```

And here is how my helper class tries to get the user list:

```
public List<String> getUsers() {
    SessionRegistry sr = (SessionRegistry) a.getBean("sessionRegistryBean");
    Object[] principals = sr.getAllPrincipals();

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < principals.length; i++) {
      SessionInformation[] sis = sr.getAllSessions(principals[i], false);
      result.add(principals[i].toString());
      logger.info("Adding entry: " + principals[i].toString() + ", sessions: " + sis.length);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Unfortunately all this doesn't work and I don't really know how to debug this. What I do is start using the applicaton (after the container-managed BASIC auth) and invoke the jsp page. The list is always empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the above mentioned configuration is that none of the beans are responsible for putting data into the `SessionRegistry`. The session events are published in the application, but more beans are needed so that authentications be put into the registry, for example an `AuthenticationManager` should be configured. Without this the `SessionRegistry` stays always empty.

Comment: Can you describe what needs to be done with the AuthenticationManager to get it to work? I'd like a way to use the SessionRegistry without enabling concurrency control.

Comment: Hi, as I remember I had to write my own `HttpSessionListener` implementation that was doing the job

Comment: @Eyal, did you found solution? (looks like i search same as you did before)

Comment: @msangel No - like jabal, I ended up writing my own HttpSessionListener implementation. I never did find a way to get the SessionRegistry working without the concurrency control.

Answer (score 1):

This have be done here: http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-querying.html

Enjoy :)

Comment: Hi, thank you, but I cannot accept this answer due to several reasons: You only linked one of the numerous Spring Security tutorials, not pointing out the mistake I made. 2, you linked a Spring Security 3 tutorial, however I mentioned 2.0.4. 3, I do not want to use all the features that are in those configs. I have to keep it as simple as possible. Authentication and authorization is configured somewhere else in my application in a totally different place. If all those beans are set up it works for me as well. The question is what I do wron in the cited config.. :-)

Comment: Could you see if there are other SessionRegistry instances by invoking getBeansOfType(SessionRegistry.class) instead of getBean("sessionRegistryBean")?