# Online/offline status in Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

In my web application I need to know whether users are online or offline. I need to update the status in the database whenever users' sessions are created or destroyed, so SessionRegistry is not an option.

I implemented it using session counters - when a user logs in, his counter increments, when he logs out or his session times out, his counter decrements.

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Service

```
@Service
public class UsersLoginLogoutListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent) { // User log in
            System.out.println("User logged in...");
            InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent iasEvent = (InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent) event;
            String userName = iasEvent.getAuthentication().getName();
            if (userName != null) {
                System.out.println("...username is " + userName + ".");
                accountService.incrementSessionCounter(userName);
            }
        }
        else if (event instanceof SessionDestroyedEvent) { // User log out / session timeout
            System.out.println("User logged out or session timeout...");
            SessionDestroyedEvent sdEvent = (SessionDestroyedEvent) event;
            List<SecurityContext> lstSecurityContext = sdEvent.getSecurityContexts();
            System.out.println("...SecurityContexts list size: " + lstSecurityContext.size() + "...");
            for (SecurityContext securityContext : lstSecurityContext)
            {
                String userName = securityContext.getAuthentication().getName();
                if (userName != null) {
                    System.out.println("...username is " + userName + ".");
                    accountService.decrementSessionCounter(userName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's been working just fine until recently, when I noticed that one counter was incremented, but never was decremented. Thanks to the logs I was able to reproduce it.

A user opens login pages in two browser tabs and logs in on one tab, then he logs in on another tab without logging out on the first tab. If he entered the correct credentials everything works fine:

> User logged in... ...username is testuser.
>
> User logged out or session timeout... ...SecurityContexts list size:
>   1... ...username is testuser.
>
> User logged in... ...username is testuser.

Even though he logged in twice using the same browser, his first session was destroyed and my counter worked correctly.
But if he entered incorrect credentials, I see the following output:

> User logged in... ...username is testuser.
>
> (After session timeout)
>
> User logged out or session timeout... ...SecurityContexts list size:
>   0...

As you can see, in this case SessionDestroyedEvent was fired, but only after the session timeout and SecurityContexts list was empty, so user's session counter wasn't decremented.

Comment: You should combine this with a `SessionRegistry`, this keeps track of the sessions and the principals belonging to a session. That way you don't have to rely on the session to contain the needed information.

Comment: @M. Deinum I'm not sure, but it seems like a very complicated solution. I thought there should be an easier way for such a simple task.

Comment: If a session is destroyed there is no garantuee that data is still available so you need another way of retrieving that information. Hence the use of a `SessionRegistry`. And why is that complicated?

Comment: In fact that data is always available, except for this very non-standard case I described. Maybe it's just a bug in Spring Security for this specific case.

It's not easy to get SessionRegistry working without special config, such as [enabling concurrency control](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5912149/).
I looked at Spring Security source code and realized that all this stuff adds a lot of unnecessary overhead.

Anyway, if you have an idea how to combine all this to get online/offline status working without complicated config like [this](http://goo.gl/8ZthZm), I'd appreciate if you could share.

Comment: Sorry I still fail to see what is complicated about 3 lines of additinal xml and adding an `@Autowired` field to your `ApplicationListener`. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/ns-config.html#ns-concurrent-sessions .

Comment: You mean just add `sessionRegistry.getSessionInformation(sdEvent.getId())` to get username for SessionDestroyedEvent? I've just tried it and it returns null.

Comment: You might have an ordering problem as the `SessionRegistryImpl` is also an `ApplicationListener` if that fires before your listener everything is cleaned up already. Add an `@Order` annotation to your listener to force it to be fired first.

Comment: @M. Deinum Thank you very much, your solution works!

I still think it's an overkill to use concurrency control and maintain SessionRegistry just to cover 0.001% of cases. I hope there's a less expensive solution.

Comment: You have to maintain the coupling sessionid <-> username somewhere I wouldn't rely on the session to do that for me. So you either come-up with your own solution our use what is available, I find the latter to work better. I wouldn't even guess to with the `SessionRegistry` (when implemented as a database instead of in-memory) you already would have your session counter as you could simply count the records for a certain user the the registry tabel.