# Limiting the number of concurrent users of a servlet

Tags: servlets, web, weblogic

I have a web application which is running in Oracle web logic server. I want to restrict the number of concurrent users who access a servlet. I tried using Semaphore that did not work. Can someone suggest how I can achieve this?

```
private static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(50);
public void doGet()
{
    try
    {
        semaphore.acquire();
        ....
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: How didn't it work? What did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: After I added semaphore, the program was not running at all.

Comment: One good option is for you to just track the number of users that have logged in with your own custom code. There are other ways to do it like Spring's SessionRegistry as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912149/getting-logged-in-users-with-a-sessionregistry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563442/how-to-set-limit-to-the-number-of-concurrent-request-in-servlet